# EmberJS: Listen for changes of an Ember object

Tags: javascript, events, ember.js, authorization

I have the following authorization route. The other routes inherited from it to restrict access base on a specific role of logged in user

```
App.AuthorizedRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(transition){
    var access = this.get('access');

    if (Em.isEmpty(access)) {
      return;
    }

    var deferred = Ember.Deferred.create();

    //----------------------------------------------------
    // trigger the following after the 'model' property in 
    // users controller is loaded

      deferred.resolve();
      return this.check(this.controllerFor('users').get('model.role'));
    //----------------------------------------------------

    return deferred;
  },

  check: function(role){
    if (this.get('access').contains(role)) {
      console.debug("[DEBUG] You are "+role+", go ahead");
      return true;
    }
    console.debug("[DEBUG] You are "+role+", you can not access to dashboard");
    this.transitionTo('users');
  }
});
```

My problem is, I don't know if Ember has some event listeners like `this.controllerFor('users').get('model').on('loaded', function(){...});` to listen for changes of an object.

I'm new on Ember. Which I should put in the comments section of the code above? Please help me with this.

**UPDATED:

I have the route /users/1/secret, and the following is the secret route, inherited from the authorization route:

```
App.UsersDashboardRoute = App.AuthorizedRoute.extend({
  access: ['admin'],
  model: function(){
    // fetch some data here
  }
});
```

So before the secret data are fetched, user1's role must be checked, by beforeModel hook. So how to know the model of users controller is already loaded, then I can call `this.check(this.controllerFor('users').get('model.role'))`

Comment: Have you tried the afterModel hook? Can you create a simple bin with your problem?

Comment: It's not a bug so I think I don't need to create bin for it. My main problem is how do I know the model in UserController has been fetched already, so I can check its 'role'?

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But my issue is listening for the event of completely loaded model from ANOTHER controller. I have updated the question clearer :)

Comment: In emberjs controllers are not generated until you enter specific route of that controller so in your case UserController will not be generated Until you enter into UserRoute. So u cannot access model of user controller until you create it.